# How can I refactor Tuple<..> to a typed class with descriptive names?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring, resharper

**Context**

I inherited a large legacy code base with heavy use of Tuple<...> types. The code is full of lines like:

```
myVar = myTuple.Item4;
```

I would like to refactor this code to make more readable by introducing custom classes with descriptive property names.

**Question**

Is any tool what supports this refactor operation efficiently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this answer won't be exactly what you hoped for, but since I have been there I thought I'd share the way I did it.

Unfortunately, I did not find a way to fully automate this refactoring using some tools. However, I approached the issue like this...

If the Tuples are used to represent a single class which you want to introduce now, you are lucky. I guess this is not the case so you will have to do a bit of a triage.

But first things first...

### Look for the Tuples

I looked up all the places where `Tuple` is used.

Both standalone Visual Studio and Resharper can help you with that by using *Find Usages* or *Find Usages Advanced* (if the Tuples are created using `Tuple.Create()`).

Otherwise or additionaly, you will need to search you solution for `new Tuple<` or just `Tuple`.

With that information, identifiy the first **class** that needs to be introduced.

### 1. Create the `class`

... and let it look like a `Tuple` for now. XML-Doc can help when Dealing with the class later on in the refatoring.

```
class ClassThatWasMissing
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents some Property.
    /// </summary>
    int Item1 { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents some other Property.
    /// </summary>
    string Item2 { get; set; }
}
```

### 2. Swap out `Tuple`-creation with declarations and initializations of your `ClassThatWasMissing`

```
- Tuple<int, string> myvar = new Tuple<int, string>();
+ ClassThatWasMissing myvar = new ClassThatWasMissing();
  myvar.Item1 = 42;
  myvar.Item2 = "Some information";
```

### 3. Refactor the `ClassThatWasMissing`

Give the Properties (`Item{n}`) more desciptive names. The comments from above can come in handy at this point.

Again, both Resharper and standalone Visual Studio can help with that (e.g. R#: Refactor → Rename):

```
class ClassThatWasMissing
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents some Property.
    /// </summary>
    int SomeProperty { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents some other Property.
    /// </summary>
    string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Also keep in mind at this point that sometimes it might be easier to apply the names at points of usage, not at points of declaration, because their purpose might be more obvious at those points. Both VS and R# are capable of renaming properties from there.

```
ClassThatWasMissing myvar = new ClassThatWasMissing();
myvar.SomeProperty = 42;
myvar.SomeOtherProperty = "Some information";
```

### Repeat the Process

...for all the places you initially or consecutivley found. Do that until there are no `Tuple`s left (or at least just the ones you can live with).

Good luck!

Comment: Note that this answer doesn't cover the equality check provided by Tuple, and thus is not a perfectly function-reproducing refactor!

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio 2022 one can highlight the tuple and change it to a struct. For example:

`public List<(string opName, string fileName)> GenerateTable()`

Right click and select `Quick Actions and Refactorings` (or  <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>) and one is offered to change it to a struct.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

(Visiting the question in 2021)

If available, you could refactor to c# 7+ [Tuple types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples).

I think the process would have 2 stages:

1. Regex the declaration from `Tuple<Type1, Type2 ...>` to `(Type1 Item1, Tupe2 Item2 ...)`
2. Rename (e.g. with VS's `Crtl+R`, `Ctrl+R`) from `Item1` to `AmazingName`, `Item2` to `EvenBetterName`, ....

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a transformer tool for if you are like me and likes to create your tuples in the return statement and name all your values. It can transform inputs like this:

```
(
  entry: x
  , title: f.GetString("title.en-US", "")
  , date: f.GetString("date.en-US", "")
  , firstComplaint: f.GetString("firstComplaint.en-US", "") == "Nej" ? false : true
)
```

Into:

```
new TupleGoneClass()
{
  Entry =  x,
  Title = f.GetString("title.en-US", ""),
  Date = f.GetString("date.en-US", ""),
  FirstComplaint = f.GetString("firstComplaint.en-US", "") == "Nej" ? false : true,
}
```

And:

```
internal class TupleGoneClass
{
    public object Entry { get; set; }
    public object Title { get; set; }
    public object Date { get; set; }
    public object FirstComplaint { get; set; }
}
```

```js
function refactor() {
  var source = document.querySelector("#input").value.trim();
  var lines = source
    .replace(/^\(|\)$/g, "").trim() // trim outher ( )
    .split(/\r?\n/);
  var props = [];
  var linesNew = [];
  lines.forEach((line) => {
    let name;
    if (line.match(/^\s*,/)) {
      // ", hejp: xxxx"
      name = line.substring(line.indexOf(",")+1, line.indexOf(":")).trim();
      name = name[0].toUpperCase() + name.substr(1);
      linesNew.push(line.substring(0, line.indexOf(",")) + " " + name + " =" + line.substring(line.indexOf(":") + 1) + ",");
    }
    else {//if (line.match(/,\s*$/)) {
      // "hejp: xxxx," or "hejp: xxxx"
      name = line.substring(line.search(/\S/), line.indexOf(":")).trim();
      name = name[0].toUpperCase() + name.substr(1);
      linesNew.push(line.substring(0, line.search(/\S/)) + name + " =" + line.substring(line.indexOf(":") + 1).replace(/,\s*$/, "") + ",");
    }
    props.push(`public object ${name} { get; set; }`);
  });
  document.querySelector("#output_source").value = `new TupleGoneClass()
{
  ${linesNew.join("\r\n")}
}`;
  document.querySelector("#output_class").value = `internal class TupleGoneClass\r\n{\r\n    ${props.join("\r\n    ")}\r\n}`;
}
refactor();
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 7em;
}

textarea[readonly] {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

dd {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<dl>
<dt>Source: </dt><dd><textarea id="input">(
  entry: x
  , title: f.GetString("title.en-US", "")
  , date: f.GetString("date.en-US", "")
  , firstComplaint: f.GetString("firstComplaint.en-US", "") == "Nej" ? false : true
)</textarea><br>
Paste your tuple here. Every value must be named. Values must be on separate lines. Commas can be placed before of after.<br>
<button onclick="refactor();">Run</button>
</dd>
<dt>Source transformed: </dt><dd><textarea id="output_source" readonly></textarea></dd>
<dt>Class: </dt><dd><textarea id="output_class" readonly></textarea></dd>
</dl>
```